# Reduce vertical space between large table and text located above to fit in the same page

Tags: spacing, threeparttable

I need to fit one portion of text and threeparttable (fixed position in the manuscript) underneath, on a single page but I am not being able to. The table is large and would only fit in one page. One solution would be to reduce font size of the table or change the text format to eliminate large space between text (above) and table below.Please advise.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Title of the table}\label{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
%\centering
\scriptsize
\hspace{-3cm}
\rotatebox{0}{
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end document
```

Any feedback is highly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Is it *that* large, ot is it that some cells should spread on several lines? Could give a MWE rather than a sort of template?

Comment: Bernard, the article I am preparing is a manuscript to be published, I am afraid that sharing the data would not be possible, however,I can always explain to you my situation further. On page 8 of the pdf output, there are 6 written lines only, after which there's empty space. The Table is located on page 9.

Comment: You don't need to include the actual table.  A \rule the same size will do.

Comment: John, could you elaborate a bit further? How can I provide you with the table's dimensions from Latex document?Thanks!

Comment: if the text is self contained (not beginning with a sentence continued from the previous page), perhaps within the `table` environment you could put it in a `minipage` with the text above the caption.  then you'd only have to make sure that the table (with text) is printeded on the proper page.

Comment: Barbara, thanks a lot for your reply. The text is a part of a section already started in the previous page and NOT a self contained part. Any other idea you can think of? Thanks again!

Comment: @Lollati -- this is really a hack, but if there's enough space between where the text would be at the top of the page and the first visible material in the figure, you could put `\vspace*{-2pc}` (or other suitable dimension) inside the figure at the top, and specify the `[b]` option on the figure instead of `[p]` (a "page" figure will *never* allow any text on the same page).  by the way, a `@` preceding the name of someone you want to notify about a comment will put a note in their tex.sx inbox; i just happened to check back and saw your comment.

Comment: @barbara beeton - Thanks a lot for your time, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work out. Would the same commands apply to a "Table" as well, because I have a table. When I entered the suggested commands, the table got pushed at the end of the document. The main cause that lead to this problem was changing citations from numerical style to author-year form, which expanded the document slightly and consequently changed the document's format. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lollati -- oops -- i meant `table`, but the principle should apply equally to any float.  a negative `\vspace` will reduce the perceived (to latex) height of any "boxed" object; at the top (use `\vspace*`), it will make it "move upward", and at the bottom, it will "shift the object down", allowing an object at the bottom of a page to descend into the margin.  using this hack is always a last resort, but worth remembering when nothing else works.  but if the object is still larger than the space available, out of luck.

Comment: You don't need to use the actual data, you can for example make a single row containing something like ``This & is & just & to & make & an & example & table & \ldots \\`` and make multiple copies of that line until the table is the same size as your original table. That said, what about adding `\small` right after `\begin{table}`? This reduces the font size of the table, as you suggested yourself.